# C# formatting XML document output with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, formatting

I've XmlDocument created by web service serialization like this (header not shown):

```
<request xmlns="a">
    <value1>1</value1>
    <value2>2</value2>
</request>
```

Is there any way how to get string representation of XmlDocument like this:

```
<ns:request xmlns:ns="a">
    <ns:value1>1</ns:value1>
    <ns:value2>2</ns:value2>
</ns:request>
```

without manually iterating and formatting?

UPDATE: The reason is, that one of the many destination systems requires such formatting while other not. I know, that I can use for example Razor template and WebRequest for this system, but I'm trying to find universal solution, in this case by using IClientMessageInspector.

Comment: Use the Regex class?

Comment: Not really - there is no magical function in any of XML APIs that adds prefixes... (and this is really wrong thing to want :) ). Note that code is somewhat trivial, but it sounds like you already know how to write it.

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit more. It seems you are looking to transform the XML once you get it from the service, and you want to use C#. Is that right? If so, why would using the Regex class not work?

Comment: @Melanie you can't parse xml with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use the `XDocument` API rather than `XmlDocument`, you could do it like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse( @"<request xmlns=""a"">
                                          <value1>1</value1>
                                          <value2>2</value2>
                                   </request>");     

xDoc.Root.ReplaceAttributes(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns", "a"));
string xmlOut = xDoc.ToString();
```

Which produces this output:

```
<ns:request xmlns:ns="a">
   <ns:value1>1</ns:value1>
   <ns:value2>2</ns:value2>
</ns:request>
```